# Yii 2 Время login и logout

Tags: php, yii2

Yii 2 Узнать время входа пользователя (login), время выхода пользователя (logout).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Comment: При входе/выходе пользователя фиксировать в таблице users время. Как вариант last_login, last_logout

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вам необходимо создать 2 поля в БД в таблице пользователей.
Первое поле - дата последнего входа, второе поле - дата выхода. 
При авторизации пользователя записываете первую дату, при logout - вторую, но со второй датой есть нюанс. Для того, что бы разлогиниться - не обязательно совершать logout. Я бы записывал дату последней активности пользователя в системе и по ней бы смотрел.